# Get beginning of path including specified subdirectory

Tags: python, path, filepath

I am looking for a way to create a new path from a given path, where the new path includes the beginning of the original path and ends with a specified subdirectory of the original path.

Original path: `/foo/bar/foobar.txt`

Specified subdirectory: `'bar/'`

New path: `/foo/bar/`

Comment: Take a look at `os` lib : 
[Join elements to make a path](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)
[Make a directory](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html#os.mkdir)

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pathlib

orig = pathlib.Path('/foo/bar/foobar.txt')

print(orig.parents[0])

# Prints:
# /foo/bar
```

Comment: Code only answers might solve the problem in hand, but lose value for future readers. Try to expand your answer with even a slight explanation of your code, or maybe a link to some of the libraries you used for more reference